# Simple way to play sound at intervals even when phone is locked and silent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alarms

Is there a simple way to play a sound at certain set intervals that will play even if the phone is locked and in silent mode? In essence it would act as an alarm, but I don't want an activity to come on screen, I simply want a sound played in the background. I plan to make an interface to enable/disable and set the intervals as well.